# VS 2013 Web breakpoints for javascript in embedded objects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, svg

Using Visual Studio 2013 Express Web and IE11 for developing a JavaScript client application which makes extensive use of SVG widgets embedded using the HTML5 object tag and is working well. However I have not worked out how in VS to have breakpoints set in the SVG widget javascript, as VS ignores breakpoints in the widget. I can hack it by adding garbage text at the location I want the breakpoint so that execution in IE stops and passes back to VS with the error however I'd like to use proper VS breakpoints if possible in the embedded object's javascript. VS breakpoints work as expected in the parent JavaScript.

As the server side uses .NET I'd prefer for consistency reasons to stick with debugging in the VS IDE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this isn't a common scenario as there are no replies. For those that come to this question later, I can sort of work around this by typing garbage into the next line which halts the debugger and allows you to use mouse hover to inspect variables as well as the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to add an extra line with the keyword 'debugger' to the embedded code and the browser will break at that point, passing over to VS Web. This is better that typing garbage in to halt the browser because if the routine is in a try/catch block the exception is caught rather than halting the debugger.

Pretty much as functional as using breakpoints in VS! I hope this helps someone else who has the same question.

Comment: Also note that this is only needed if you have javascript in a svg embedded object. If the object is HTML you can set breakpoints.